# "got our sleeping bags unrolled" vs "unrolled our sleeping bags"

Tags: word-usage

Can you explain to me the ussage of "got our sleeping bags unrolled". The text in my book is:

> When we **got our sleeping bags unrolled**, I pulled out a bag of Double Stuf Oreos.

Can I say it without "got":

When we unrolled our sleeping bags, I pulled out a bag of Double Stuf Oreos.

What difference is for English people between "we got our sleeping bags unrolled" and "we unrolled our sleeping bags"?

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the "when" part of the sentence. "When we unrolled our sleeping bags, I pulled out a bag..." would mean you pulled out the bag at the same time you were unrolling the sleeping bags. "When we got the sleeping bags unrolled, I pulled out a bag..." means when the sleeping bags were in a unrolled state, I pulled out the bag.

Without the "when" and the "I pulled out a bag of Double Stuf Oreos" parts, yes the two the sentences are pretty much the same, but you have to take the entire sentence as a whole, and thus, there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

@pboss3010 answered the first question pretty well (it's sequential action vs simultaneous action), so I'll focus on the second question.

> What difference is for English people between "we got our sleeping
>   bags unrolled" and "we unrolled our sleeping bags"?

They seem interchangeable, and would often be used as such, but there are some differences.

"We unrolled our sleeping bags" is more active voice, and as such often preferred stylistically

Also, "we got our sleeping bags unrolled" can be unclear - did the speaker unroll their sleeping bag themselves, or did someone else unroll it on their behalf? Usually context would make this clear, but there is more ambiguity that in the first sentence.